# Bootstrap + SASS: Is there a way to include "just the stuff you need"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to not include wells or sliders or any other UI components that I won't be using in my pages? Would it be possible to be able to add those UI components later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customized Bootstrap styles are already compiled to css, so if you want to use sass I recommend not using this tool.

There is a Bootstrap [sass version](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass). Download it, go to vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap and open `bootstrap.scss` file. Here are the sass partials, if you don't want to use any of these you can comment it to prevent from being imported. If in addition you want to remove a partial file you can do it but remember that also you should remove it from `bootstrap.scss`

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your Bootstrap here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/